# How can i auto scroll two same vertical long image one after other repeatedly?

Tags: javascript, css, npm, frontend, css-animations

I am trying to achieve something like in website https://minimals.cc/ where the first vertical image is moving downwards and after the image reach its top the same image starts from its bottom.
So, there are two images moving downwards.

I searched for some npm library but didn't worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page uses something like a `requestAnimationFrame()`-loop and modifies the transform css property of the image with [`translateY(N%)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateY).

```js
let direction = 1;
(function loop(percent) {
  // decreasing the speed value, slows down the scrolling
  const speed = 0.25;
  
  // adjust the passed value, starting with 0 going to -100
  percent -= direction * speed;

  // set the new style property
  example.style.transform = `translateY(${percent}%)`;

  // invert the direction, if the 0 or -100 is reached
  if (percent <= -100 || percent >= 0)
    direction *= -1;

  requestAnimationFrame(() => loop(percent));
})(0)
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100vw;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<img id="example" src="https://i.imgur.com/zVQzmPI.png">
```